# Using GROUP BY winth JOIN

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I am having problems using GROUP BY and JOIN

I have 2 tables: 
 1. STUDENTS_TO_COURSE with course_id and student_id columns
 2. Students with id, name, age columns

What I need to do is to find a course with highest average student age

I was thinking about using join to unite these tables and then to group it somehow

I also understand that I need to use AVG to count average student age on the joined table

```
select STUDENTS_TO_COURSE.course_id as course_id, 
students.id as student, 
students.age as age 
from STUDENTS_TO_COURSE
join students on STUDENTS_TO_COURSE.student_id = students.id
```

I was thinking about for for a few days now, but couldn't come up with any idea

Is there any clue how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select STUDENTS_TO_COURSE.course_id as course_id, 
MAX(AVG(age)) as avg_age
from STUDENTS_TO_COURSE
join students on STUDENTS_TO_COURSE.student_id = students.id
group by course_id,age
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer really helped me
Although your solution wasn't working correctly, I managed to improve it a bit and got a right answer
The right one is 
`select STUDENTS_TO_COURSE.course_id as course_id, 
AVG(age) as avg_age
from STUDENTS_TO_COURSE
join students on STUDENTS_TO_COURSE.student_id = students.id
group by course_id
order by avg_age desc
limit 1`

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL code is correct, the following gets a list of course IDs and average ages in decreasing order of average age.
What you want is the top line of the list.

```
select 
   STUDENTS_TO_COURSE.course_id as course_id, 
   AVG(students.age) as avg_age
from STUDENTS_TO_COURSE
join students on STUDENTS_TO_COURSE.student_id = students.id
GROUP BY STUDENTS_TO_COURSE.course_id
ORDER BY AVG(students.age) DESC
```